# Hacer uso de json_encode para imagen en PHP

Tags: php, json

Que tal, quiero hacer uso de `json_encode` para hacer un json de una imagen obtenida de la base de datos, esto tengo pero no me funciona solo me manda la página en blanco y no muestra nada de `json`:

```
<?php
 define('HOST','host.com');
 define('USER','usuario');
 define('PASS','contraseña');
 define('DB','baseDatos');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

  $sql = "select imagenes from imagenes";

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 /*$resultado= mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $resultado['imagenes'] ).'"/>';*/


 $result = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 array_push($result,array('url'=>$row['imagenes']));
 }


 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Cabe señalar que tengo 2 imágenes en la base de datos y son de tipo `BLOB`

Answer (score 2):

Esto podría ayudarte

**PHP**

```
ob_start();
imagepng($my_img);
$imageData = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean(); 

$results = array(
  'price' => $_GET['priceX'],
  'image' => base64_encode($imageData)
);

$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

**Javascript**

```
$.getJSON("/ajax-script.php", function(data) {
  $("#element").append($("<img />").attr('src', 'data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,' + data.image));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Las URL pueden poseer caracteres especiales, por lo cual, si esa URL de imagen específica los posee, al ingresarla al array el código va a detectar los caracteres especiales no escapados y vas a tener un error. Por lo tanto, lo que podrías probar es algo como esto:

```
$result = array();

$src =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['imagenes']);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, array('url'=> $src));
}
```

Prueba si eso te funciona. La URL debería guardarse con los caracteres especiales "escapados", y de esa manera deberías poder obtener la URL dentro de tu array sin problema alguno.